# WPF DataGrid DateTime.Now DatePicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datepicker

I have a datepicker in a Datagrid row. What I want is when a user clicks in the row and the datepicker that the date goes to today's date.

This code below does work if you go straight to the datepicker and then go and pick a date, **however the problem is when you click inside the row first then the datepicker goes to 01/01/0001.**

I have this XAML but it does not work.

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"></DatePicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Any help would be grateful

Comment: maybe SelectedDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now.Date}"

Comment: If you have it declare `System` at root level, then it will work fine. I was under assumption you are using namespace directly. I tried in small app and it works fine.

Comment: With the 4.0 framework, it causes a Stackoverflow exception.. (without sp1)

Comment: Ok I see the problem, the code does work if you go straight to the datepicker and pick a date, but it goes to 01/01/0001 when you click inside the row, so I guess I need to set the Date when the row is clicked on

Comment: Ok I found the answer but I cant post it yet, will do it later, and here it is 

because I have an event InitializingNewItem that fires when I click inside a row inside the datagrid, so I need to set the underline object in c# to equal today's date,


        private void DataGrid_InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
        {
          <t> row = e.NewItem as <t>;
            row.DateTimeObject = DateTime.Now;
        }